# Together forever to the stars in latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

How would I write “Together forever, to the stars” in Latin please? I am looking at getting a ring engraved and would like this on the inside. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to the site! Can you [edit] and add more context, please? For example, who are the people or things that are together? Latin cares about gender.

Answer (score 2):

I like the approach taken by Vincent in his answer; however, I would make a few tweaks:

- The verb *coniungere* for "unite" seems more suitable than *coniugare*. It is the word for (among other things) people joined in friendship, love or marriage. There is a particular connection to marriage, and the derived noun *coniunx* means spouse. (By the way, you could also use *unire*, from which the English "unite" ultimately derives, but it is not a common expression in Latin.)
- I would use a passive perfect form like in English.
- For "forever," we should perhaps allow ourselves a little more flourish than *semper*. Perhaps *in aeternum, in pepetuum* or *in omne tempus*.

So I would for example suggest:

> In aeternum coniuncti ad astra.

Comment: I like this suggestion a lot. I'd only add a note on gender: If the people being united are all female, it's the feminine *coniunctae*, but if there's at least one male, it's the masculine *coniuncti*, and neuter is an option only if it's not about people.

Answer (score 0):

What I can contribute

Semper coniugēmus, ad astra.

Comment: Hi Valens, and welcome to the site! Could you explain more why this answers the question? Why is _conjugemus_ the best choice for "together", for example?

Comment: Did you perhaps rather mean to use the verb *coniungere* instead of the pretty rare *coniugare*? (Even so, I would have used a passive form.)

Comment: As Simon mentions its the ring that he wants to engrave. I think it's for his marriage. I think of word 'coniūnx' but want to pick the verb. And yes, coniungere' should be more commonly used. Somehow the word 'coniugō' was reflected in my mind. Perhaps the passive form is more suitable. (I may be too ambitious to give my first answer :p)

Comment: Feel free to edit your post and add this information in. It's fine to offer an imperfect translation, but a good answer explains why you have translated it that way. (You can also tweak it as necessary!)

Answer (score 0):

There are many good answers to this question. Here are a few:

*Semper conjuges, ad astra*, always joined together, to the stars.

*Semper conjuncti, ad astra*, pretty much the same as above, but with more emphasis on the verb "join together".

Or you can do two rings: his and hers: *Semper conjunctus, ad astra* for him, and *Semper conjuncta, ad astra* for her.